# Can this code throw an access violation exception

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

Consider this code:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(unsigned char * tempbuf, T val, int &nMatches, int nSize)
{
    T temp_val;
    for (int offset = 0; offset < nSize; ++offset)
    {
        temp_val = *((T*)&tempbuf[offset]);
        if (temp_val == val)
        {
            ++nMatches;
        }               
    }
}
int main ()
{
    int nValue = 5;
    int nMatches(0);
    const int size = 1000;
    unsigned char *buffer = reinterpret_cast <unsigned char *>(malloc(size));
    foo(buffer, nValue, nMatches, size);
    return 1;
}
```

Considering nValue is an int, foo will read the 1000th byte of the buffer as an int (eg at least 32 bit variables). Does this mean that an exception could be thrown because of an access violation on non allocated memory? (assuming int is 4 bytes, 3 bytes might not exist on the last read and if they do exist they might have garbage value so I know it's at least UB, but considering the address to read is itself valid I am not sure about the exception).

Comment: What happened when you ran it? Wouldn't you see the access violation yourself?

Comment: Reading out of bounds is UB, but what will happens nobody can really say. Just *reading* will most likely not cause a crash of any kind though (but don't quote me on that!)

Comment: You know what they say about assumptions, right? (in particularly, about "assuming int is 4 bytes").

Comment: This is a very simplified version of a memory scanner program which I coded therefore I've never ran this sample but I used to have the UB (which I fixed) and I never had an exception which I find odd

Comment: Also, you have another case of UB, in that you read *uninitialized data*. The memory you allocate with `malloc` (why not `new unsigned char[1000]`?) is not initialized so its contents will be *indeterminate*.

Comment: Your code is definitely a minefield. Amongst many bad things that will happen, the CPU can throw exceptions on wrong Alignment... You are reading integers at 1 byte offsets

Comment: @Some programer dude I thought I needed not construct memory for built in type considering T can be int/float/byte/short/double/longlong in my program, I didn't know on which type to construct the memory either

Comment: @user What you are doing is dangerous. See [this article].(http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/pa-dalign/)

Comment: Considering that `char` (and automatically `unsigned char`) is the smallest addressable unit on any system, if you use `malloc` or `new[]` doesn't matter. Both will allocate the same number of bytes. With `new[]` at least you don't have to cast the result, *and* it's a more C++-ish way of allocating memory.

Comment: @WhiZtim I had no idea this could happen, is std::move the best option in order to scan byte by byte and yet respect alignement (moving the whole block by 1 byte, 3 times

Comment: Regarding the alignment issue, considering that you have an array of bytes you can't really start fetching the larger types from anywhere, you must start on proper alignment. Then when you loop over the array you should increase the byte-offset by the types alignment. This can all be easily done with the [`alignof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignof) construct. Just use `alignof(T)` when and where needed.

Comment: I have a fast scan option that already respects alignement. However I must have an option that does scan for types, byte by byte. In the latest case should I scan the whole block by chuncks of alignof(T), then move the block by 1 byte  (std::move) and do it over and over (sizeof(T) -1) times?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Regarding your second comment: Shouldn't the fact that the type is `unsigned char`, which means that no trap representations are possible, prevent UB as long as you only read from the uninitialised data and not attempt the `int*` cast?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I have carefully read this great article although it seems to be outdated (2005) and newer articles on this subject will report very different conclusions such as [this one](http://lemire.me/blog/2012/05/31/data-alignment-for-speed-myth-or-reality/) (2012)which claims not only that reading out of alignment is safe, but has nearly no cost : "Your laptop only needs alignment for fancy operations, such as SSE instructions" & "On recent Intel processors (Sandy Bridge and Nehalem), there is no performance penalty for reading or writing misaligned memory operands."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assumptions are the following:

- You're aware, that reading outside of allocated buffer is a terrible practice
- We aren't talking about "how to fix code", but only about "what may happen"

As you mentioned, on the last iteration of loop within `foo()` you are reading several bytes outside the allocated buffer. Access to random memory is always a possibility for crashing with [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault), but in this particular case chances of bad outcome are insignificant, but still nonzero. Reasons:

- buffer is allocated within heap, so bytes right after the buffer are likely to be part of the heap as well (unless buffer is positioned right on the heap border), so reading will return garbage with no failures.
- even going outside of the heap may not hit you. It's almost impossible to predict, what memory are you going to read especially considering [address randomization technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization). You have chances for good and bad outcome (e.g. heap on the border of address space will definitely result into reading fault). According to Google, great insights on virtual memory mapping can be obtained by experimenting with [VMMap](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd535533.aspx) utility, but I didn't do it for myself.

So the bottom line is that your program has ticking bomb within, but it's unclear if we will live to see explosion.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I'll simply point out that the algorythms got fixed a while ago(eg I no longer read out of block) (or so I thought, because I still read out of alignment). But I looked back at the old code and though "Why didn't that ever throw, after hundreds of gigabytes of memory read ?". This clarifies it.